# not found [No such file or directory] error, even though the file present in that directory on RH Linux 6.2

Tags: linux, shell

When I’m executing a script from Linux (RH Linux 6.2), it is giving not found [No such file or directory] error, even though the file is present in that directory (checked the permissions and they are fine).

**Example:**

```
md1silinux04:/data/upgrade> /data/upgrade/upgrade_db.ksh
-ksh: /data/upgrade/upgrade_db.ksh: not found [No such file or directory]

md1silinux04:/data/RAIL/rpo402/db/upgrade> ls /data/upgrade/upgrade_db.ksh
/data/upgrade/upgrade_db.ksh
```

Could anybody please help on this ?

Comment: Update it with this output:
ls -ls /data/RAIL/rpo402/db/upgrade

Comment: can you paste the permissions (ls -l /data/RAIL/rpo402/db/upgrade)? are you sure the file has execute permission (chmod +x)?

Comment: What is the size of the file? Make sure it isn't empty. Also, what is the first line of the file?

Comment: I really hope you're not using Red Hat Linux 6.2. You mean Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.2, surely?

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps you have ctrl-M (carriage returns) at the end of each line in your file.

To view:
`cat -v /data/upgrade/upgrade_db.ksh`

To fix:
`perl -p -i -e "s/\r//g" /data/upgrade/upgrade_db.ksh`

Answer (score 0):

Enter this:

```
ls -ls /data/RAIL/rpo402/db/upgrade
```

List the output for the file and look at it's permissions.

Make sure the file isn't empty.
Make sure the file has permissions to be executed as a shell.

```
chmod +x upgrade_db.ksh
```

Look at the first line of the file, make sure it has a proper header for a shell script. Maybe Korn Shell requires the shell declaration in the header.

Check dmesg to see if there are any error messages, perhaps the file system and check inodes.

Comment: ... still getting the same problem(file is not empty, execute permissions are there and executed ls -ls ..... ).

Comment: RH 6.2 I have declared #!/bin/ksh in the first line

Comment: Could it be the machine has lost sanity? The file system is messed up, perhaps out of inodes? Are you able to reboot the machine?

Comment: I'll check the reboot option.

Comment: Try executing it like this:
ksh -x ./upgrade_db.ksh
in the same directory it resides in.

Comment: Try creating another file there and see if it works. Something simple like myfile.ksh and have it print Hello World.

Comment: @Edward... I have removed the file and created again.. oh now it is working. Seems the problem with inode messup.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

- ksh /data/upgrade/upgrade_db.ksh

or while you have a current irectory the data/upgrade/

- . ./upgrade_db.ksh

Answer (score 0):

Although not likely the OP's issue, a similar-enough error message - it brought me here - can occur if your shebang has the  character.  In my case, the script still executes, but the error is very annoying - especially since I'm helping somebody with their 'official' procedure and errors are unwelcome in such cases.

Example output:

```
CS-015: # /bin/ksh check.sh  
check.sh[1]: ﻿#!/bin/ksh: cannot execute - No such file or directory
check.sh
```

Resulting from what cat shows as:

```
$ cat check.sh
#!/bin/ksh

THIS_SCRIPT="$(basename $0)"

echo "$THIS_SCRIPT"
exit 0
# Nothing else matters; I had narrowed it to here...
```

In this case, I had inherited the file and a hexdump shows:

```
$ hexdump -C check.sh
00000000  ef bb bf 23 21 20 2f 62  69 6e 2f 6b 73 68 0a 0a  |...#! /bin/ksh..|
00000010  54 48 49 53 5f 53 43 52  49 50 54 3d 22 24 28 62  |THIS_SCRIPT="$(b|
...
```

As [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) suggests at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381263/17300, you can remove this with sed:

```
$ sed -i '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' check.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today.

```
-ksh: line 24: run-pipeline: not found
```

I went through the posts, but couldn't find the solution/explanation, I checked these:

- File definitely existed
- $PATH included the path, where the file was
- I tried out other shells as well (bash)
- File did not contain strange chars (dos2unix, cat -v)
- No permission issues (chmod +x and sudo)

It turned out that the path in the first line of the file was too long:

```
#!/extremely/long/path/that/was/more/than/128/chars/long/python3.6
def rest_of_the_script():
```

Moved python3.6 to a shorter path (less than 128 chars), and everything worked!